# Unable to sort the JTable by Date

Tags: java, swing, sorting, user-interface, jtable

I have a JTable, where the first column of it is a Date. However, this is not actually a `Date` object, it is a `String` which display the date in UK format. Below is my code

```
private class DisplayAllRevenue extends ComponentAdapter
     {
         @Override
         public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e)
         {
             DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) allRevenueTable.getModel();
             model.setRowCount(0);


             dbConnector = new DBHandler();
             dbConnector.makeConnection();

             java.sql.Date dateOfLastUpdate=null;


             ResultSet portfolioRs = dbConnector.selectAllDetails(getPortfolioData);

             try
             {
                 if(portfolioRs.isBeforeFirst()==false)
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Empty");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     while(portfolioRs.next())
                     {
                         String provider = portfolioRs.getString("Provider Name");
                         String client = portfolioRs.getString("Client Name");
                         int idPortfolio = portfolioRs.getInt("idPortfolio");
                         dateOfLastUpdate = portfolioRs.getDate("Update_Date");


                         String dateOfLastUpdateS = getDateInUKFormat(convertSQLDateToJavaDate(dateOfLastUpdate));

                         Object[]row3 = {dateOfLastUpdateS, provider, client, idPortfolio};

                         model.addRow(row3);
                         }

                     }

                    //Sort the Table
                    DefaultRowSorter sorter = ((DefaultRowSorter)allRevenueTable.getRowSorter()); 
                    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                    list.add( new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.DESCENDING) );
                    sorter.setSortKeys(list);
                    sorter.sort();
                 }
             }
             catch(SQLException sql)
             {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error displaying data");
                 sql.printStackTrace();
             }
             finally
             {
                 dbConnector.closeConnection();
             }
         }
     }
```

As you can see, I am trying to sort the table by the `Date`. But unfortunately, it didn't work! Everything just went out of order. I am wondering this because the `Date` is actually a `String`.

So, how can I sort by table "correctly" according to the Date ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).  Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I am using Netbeans GUI builder. Therefore, posting that auto generated code will be a mess!

Comment: Good luck with it then.  Voting to close.

Comment: Parse the date Strings to Date objects, or better read them as Date object from the database. Put these into your table, sorting should be working then. If the appearence of the dates does not seem appropriate, create a cell renderer to customize it.

Comment: @stefan: and that is what i sknt know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I am wondering this because the Date is actually a String.*

Yes, most likely. Note that you don't have to mix the data contained in the table model with its representation. In this case you could perfectly have a `Date` object and show it in UK format or whatever format you like. Even better, for internationalization trade you could let the table cell renderer/editor resolve the current locale and apply a date format accordingly.

The whole matter is about retrieving the appropriate class in the table model implementation by overriding [getColumnClass(columnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass-int-) method. If we do this correctly, then `JTable` component will be able to:

- Provide an appropriate renderer/editor. See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- Auto create row sorters with the ability to sort the rows as expected.

For a better explanation see [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section of [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial. But in a nutshell:

> To determine which `Comparator` to use for a column, `TableRowSorter`
>   attempts to apply each of the following rules in turn. Rules are
>   followed in the order listed below; the first rule that provides the
>   sorter with a `Comparator` is used, and the remainining rules ignored.
>
> 1. If a comparator has been specified by invoking `setComparator`, use that comparator.
> 2. If the table model reports that the column data consists of strings (T`ableModel.getColumnClass` returns `String.class` for that
>      column), use a comparator that sorts the strings based on the current
>      locale.
> 3. If the column class returned by `TableModel.getColumnClass` implements `Comparable`, use a comparator that sorts the strings based
>      on the values returned by `Comparable.compareTo`.
> 4. If a string convertor has been specified for the table by invoking `setStringConverter`, use a comparator that sorts the resulting string
>      representations based on the current locale.
> 5. If none of the previous rules apply, use a comparator that invokes `toString` on the column data and sorts the resulting strings based on
>      the current locale.

Since `Date` class implements `Comparable` interface, then it's a case of point 3. So, once again, overriding `getColumnClass()` correctly will lead you to solve your problem.

---

#### Off-topic

Please note database calls are time consuming tasks and may block the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)  causing the GUI become unresponsive. The EDT is a single and special 
thread where Swing components creation and update must be performed and event handling take place.

Having said that, take a look to this part in your code:

```
private class DisplayAllRevenue extends ComponentAdapter {
     @Override
     public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
         // Event handling code: it is performed in the EDT
     }
}
```

If you make database calls every time the component is shown then you'll have severe performance issues. You might consider add a button to let the users refresh the table's data instead of trying to do that automatically when the component is shown.

Additionally, in order to avoid blocking the EDT you might consider use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform database calls in a background thread and update Swing components in the EDT. See more in [Concurrency in Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: I found this is the corret way. I tried it but I am getting some issues. Eventhough I am having issues, since this answer is right, I am marking this as solved. Please take a look at my new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924799/invalid-sorting-on-date-in-jtable